# How can I have my triples and count them too? (Adding aggregation query results to non-aggregated solutions)

Tags: sparql

I am trying to combine the results of a certain CONSTRUCT query with a couple of aggregation statistics. The aggregation, of course, loses the individual rows. Is there a clever sparql idiom or arrangement that combines aggregated and non-aggregated results without too much fuss and repetition?

As a simplified example, let's say I want to retrieve all skos labels and also count how many labels each concept has. Here's an aggregation query that will count the labels:

```
SELECT ?s (COUNT(?o) AS ?label_count)
WHERE {
    ?s a skos:Concept .
    ?s ?p ?o 
        FILTER (?p IN (skos:prefLabel, skos:altLabel, skos:HiddenLabel))
}
GROUP BY ?s
```

So now I want to CONSTRUCT all the matched label triples, plus a triple to hold the count like this:

```
CONSTRUCT {
   ?s ?p ?o . 
   ?s ext:numLabels ?label_count .
}
WHERE {
    ????
}
```

What's the right way to put together something like this? I cannot use the WHERE query from the SELECT statement, because it produces only one solution for each concept; the predicates and labels are rolled up into the count. So how can I have my triples and count them too?

Comment: why can't you use a sub-SELECT in the `WHERE` part of your `CONSTRUCT` query? Just use the graph pattern of the `SELECT` query plus the whole `SELECT` query as a sub-`SELECT`

Comment: So you're saying I should just bite the bullet and repeat the SELECT block twice, right?

Comment: yep, basically like `CONSTRUCT {} WHERE { ?s a skos:Concept .
    ?s ?p ?o 
        FILTER (?p IN (skos:prefLabel, skos:altLabel, skos:HiddenLabel)) {SELECT ?s (COUNT(?o) AS ?label_count)
WHERE {
    ?s a skos:Concept .
    ?s ?p ?o 
        FILTER (?p IN (skos:prefLabel, skos:altLabel, skos:HiddenLabel))
}
GROUP BY ?s }  }`

Comment: the subquery is evaluated first, then joined with the outer triple patterns